# is this possible to store OTP in database at the same time as sending OTP on users mobile

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send one time password on users mobile and at the same time trying store it in database. Is this possible to do this?

Comment: Of course, have you tried it?

Comment: actually i can't understand how do this.

Comment: give me some hint please

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, this is possible. Technically, you will first write generated OTP to DB and then you will send it to the user. However, form a performance point of view, I will suggest you, use in-memory databases like Redis. Alternatively, you can store OTPs in your program variables, depending on your need. I published a module named [in-memory-otp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/in-memory-otp) at NPM for this functionality. You can also take help from there too.